# Spring Boot multi tenancy with discriminator foreign key

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, multi-tenant

Hi i'm implementing a spring boot multitenancy application where the tenant is stored in a table but I want to pass just the ID of the tenant and then intercept it and i filter with Hibernate filter for each table that i have.

```
public class TenantContext {

 private TenantContext() {}
 

    private static InheritableThreadLocal<Long> currentTenant = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setTenantId(Long tenantId) {
        System.out.println("tenantContext-setTenantId " + tenantId);
        currentTenant.set(tenantId);
    }

    public static Long getTenantId() {
        return currentTenant.get();
    }

    public static void clear(){
        currentTenant.remove();
    }

}
```

this is my tenant context class where i get the tenant id;

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptor;

import net.agm.hydra.services.LicenseService;

@Component
public class TenantInterceptor implements WebRequestInterceptor {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Autowired
LicenseService licenseService;

@Override

public void preHandle(WebRequest request) throws Exception {
     String tenantId = null;
        if (request.getHeader("X-TENANT-ID") != null) {
            tenantId = request.getHeader("X-TENANT-ID");
            logger.info("preHandle tenantId " + tenantId);
        } else {
            tenantId = ((ServletWebRequest)request).getRequest().getServerName().split("\\.")[0];
        }
        TenantContext.setTenantId(Long.parseLong(tenantId));

}

@Override
public void postHandle(WebRequest request, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
    TenantContext.clear();

}

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(WebRequest request, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

this is mt tenant interceptor, where i get the id from the header's request;

```
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreRemove;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

    import net.agm.hydra.model.License;

import net.agm.hydra.services.LicenseService;

public class TenantListener {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Autowired
LicenseService service;

    @PreUpdate
    @PreRemove
    @PrePersist
    public void setTenant(TenantAware entity) {
          logger.info("setTenant-license " + entity);
        final Long tenantId = TenantContext.getTenantId();
        License license = service.getLicenseById(tenantId);
        logger.info("setTenant-license " + license);
        entity.setLicense(license);
        }

}
```

Here is where i pass the tenant to the entity;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
private final TenantInterceptor tenantInterceptor;

@Autowired
public WebConfiguration(TenantInterceptor tenantInterceptor) {
    this.tenantInterceptor = tenantInterceptor;
}



   @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addWebRequestInterceptor(tenantInterceptor);
    }
    
    
}
```

Here i configure the interceptor ;

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Aspect
public class TenantFilterAspect {
    
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    
      @Pointcut("execution (* org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(..))")
        public void openSession() {
        }
    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "openSession()", returning = "session")
    public void afterOpenSession(Object session) {
        if (session != null && Session.class.isInstance(session)) {
            final Long tenantId = TenantContext.getTenantId();
            logger.info("afteropensession tenantId: " + tenantId);

            if (tenantId != null) {
                org.hibernate.Filter filter = ((Session) session).enableFilter("tenantFilter");
                logger.info("afteropensession filter: " + filter.getName());
                filter.setParameter("tenantId", tenantId);
              
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this is the aspect that take the tenant and embellish it on every query i do, but here looks like filter doesn't work properly;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Filter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import net.agm.hydra.config.multitenant.TenantAware;
import net.agm.hydra.config.multitenant.TenantListener;
import net.agm.hydra.model.License;

@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@FilterDef(name = "tenantFilter", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "tenantId", type = "long")})
@Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "tenantId in (:tenant_id) ")
@EntityListeners(TenantListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity implements TenantAware, Serializable{
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id")
    private License license;
  
  public BaseEntity() {}

    public BaseEntity(License license) {
        this.license = license;
        }
    
}
```

This is the base entity that i inherit on my ather entity an where the filter works, i think the problem is in this class because the tenant is not found with this configurtion.

i public also the database schema if may help

```
CREATE TABLE License(
     tenant_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     business_name  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     start_date DATE NOT NULL,
     end_date DATE NOT NULL,
     cost REAL,
     paid REAL 
);

CREATE TABLE Users(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  email    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  name      VARCHAR(255),
  surname   VARCHAR(255) ,
  password  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  workplace VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  expertise_area VARCHAR(255),
  actived VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
 tenant_id BIGINT,
 FOREIGN KEY(tenant_id) REFERENCES License ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Roles(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_fk BIGINT NOT NULL,
  role VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
 tenant_id BIGINT,
  FOREIGN KEY(user_fk) REFERENCES Users ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY(tenant_id) REFERENCES License ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  UNIQUE(role,user_fk)
);


CREATE TABLE Projects(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255),
    start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    end_date DATE NOT NULL,
    total_days INT NOT NULL,
    tenant_id BIGINT,
    FOREIGN KEY(tenant_id) REFERENCES License ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Tasks(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    task_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    project_fk BIGINT NOT NULL,
    date_of_registration DATE NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    total_worked REAL,
    date_of_publish TIMESTAMP ,
    hours_of_working REAL,
    revision INTEGER, 
    tenant_id BIGINT,
    FOREIGN KEY(tenant_id) REFERENCES License ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(project_fk) REFERENCES Projects  ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Assigned(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_fk BIGINT NOT NULL,
    task_fk BIGINT NOT NULL,
    tenant_id BIGINT,
    FOREIGN KEY(user_fk) REFERENCES Users ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(task_fk) REFERENCES Tasks  ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(tenant_id) REFERENCES License ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    UNIQUE(user_fk,task_fk)
);


CREATE TABLE Bookables(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255),
    tenant_id BIGINT,
    FOREIGN KEY(tenant_id) REFERENCES License ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Books(
      id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
      user_fk BIGINT NOT NULL,
      bookable_fk BIGINT NOT NULL,
      start_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
      end_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
      tenant_id BIGINT,
      FOREIGN KEY(user_fk) REFERENCES Users ON DELETE NO ACTION,
      FOREIGN KEY(bookable_fk) REFERENCES Bookables ON DELETE NO ACTION,
      FOREIGN KEY(tenant_id) REFERENCES License ON DELETE NO ACTION,
      UNIQUE(bookable_fk, start_date, end_date),
      CONSTRAINT CheckEndLaterThanStart CHECK (end_date >= start_date)
);
```

maybe the structure can help:

```
 2021-03-22 11:09:28.608  INFO 10780 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] n.a.h.c.multitenant.TenantFilterAspect   : afteropensession filter: tenantFilter
2021-03-22 11:09:28.638 ERROR 10780 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.processDynamicFilterParameters(JoinProcessor.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SyntheticAndFactory.addWhereFragment(SyntheticAndFactory.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.addJoinNodes(JoinProcessor.java:312) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.processJoins(JoinProcessor.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:800) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:689) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:716) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:779) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:314) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:703) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:680) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:356) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at net.agm.hydra.services.impl.UsersServiceImpl.getUsers(UsersServiceImpl.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at net.agm.hydra.apicontrollers.UsersController.gellAll(UsersController.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at net.agm.hydra.apicontrollers.UsersController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$46343f7.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at net.agm.hydra.apicontrollers.UsersController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8462392f.gellAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
```

and this is the snippet of the exceptions thrown when i try to do any request, i hope the problem is well exposed and someone have the solution for it.
thak you very mutch:

P.S excuse me if is not so clear because of my english.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution just modifying this class

```
`package net.agm.hydra.model.base;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Filter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import net.agm.hydra.config.multitenant.TenantAware;
import net.agm.hydra.config.multitenant.TenantListener;
import net.agm.hydra.model.License;
import net.agm.hydra.services.LicenseService;

@MappedSuperclass
@NoArgsConstructor
@FilterDef(name = "tenantFilter", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "tenantId", type = "long")})
@Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "tenant_id = :tenantId")
@EntityListeners(TenantListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity implements TenantAware, Serializable{

    @Autowired
    LicenseService licenseService;


    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id")
    private License license;

 

    public BaseEntity(Long tenantId) {
        //  this.tenantId = id;
        this.license = licenseService.getLicenseById(tenantId);
    }


}
```

So i build my license inside the constructor an then i assign it at my global variable license
that's it